# UIView animateWithDuration: does not animate in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios7, core-animation

In Xcode project, I have animated by using `UIView animateWithDuration:` works in iOS 6. In iOS 7, on initially launch the animation works fine. But when I enter into background and again enter into app (foreground), `UIView animateWithDuration:` does not work.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The first thought that you make some animation in viewWillAppear: method which doesn't fire at foreground transition from BG.

Comment: I can think of half-a-dozen reasons. However, until you show us how you're triggering the animation we have no way to tell. And are you saying that the animation DOES occur when you return to the foreground in iOS 6, but not iOS 7? Give us details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uiview-animations/) a quick and dirty tutorial with code sample for UIViewController & UIView animation.